# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Software Quality Assurance & Testing has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the winning moderators are:

[image: PDHide]

[image: Kate Paulk]

[image: corsiKa]

They are your [first elected moderation team](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering! Congratulations to PDHide for joining the team and to Kate Paulk and corsiKa for winning reelection!  A big thank you goes to [alecxe](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/5574/alecxe) for serving as a pro-tem moderator since 2017!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5323176172060672).